# A call to break function after a return?

Tags: java, return, break

I am using code from O'Reilly's Apache ZooKeeper book and I came across this function:

```
String queueCommand(String command) throws KeeperException
{
  while(true)
  {
    try
      {
        String name = zk.create("/task/task-", command.getBytes(), OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.SEQUENTIAL);
        return name;
        break;
      } catch (NodeExistsException e) {
        throw new Exception(name + " already appears to be running");
      } catch (ConnectionLossException e) { }
  }
}
```

Is this just a mistake? Am I correct in that the break statement is useless?

Comment: Compiler should mark this with an "unreachable code" warning.

Comment: No, the `break` statement is useful ... for determining which publishers have lousy editors.

Comment: Also, this code would not have compiled, because of another mistake - see the scope of String var name, and then its used in the catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the `return` statement has been reached, no further code will execute within that method. Therefore, in this case the `break` statement will never actually be reached, so you are right that it is not necessary. I'm guessing that the person who wrote it was just trying to be extra (read: too) careful.

In fact, the compiler should give you an `unreachable code` warning when you compile this, as it will recognize that you have operations listed in an unreachable part of your program.

In general it is very bad practice to have any operations directly following a `return` statement for this very reason.

Answer (score 1):

A `break;` statement (or any other statement) after your `return name;` statement won't compile. Unreachable code.

Answer (score 1):

`return` is like `break` for full functions instead of loops and switches. So yes.

Comment: Not really a good analogy, because `return` can have data attached to it, while `break` cannot.

Comment: Thats true. Just the basic concept of "Leave"